# aio-pika: Seems like connection is not closed while running using asyncio.run()

Tags: python-3.x, pika, python-asyncio

As of python3.7 it is recommended to use asyncio.run() to start the coroutine. I am using asyncio.run to start my program that connects to rabbitmq using aio-pika. But when I press Ctrl + C to send KeyboardInterrupt exception to stop the program, it looks like aio-pika tries to close the connection but hangs.

```
import asyncio
import aio_pika

async def process_message(message: aio_pika.IncomingMessage):
    async with message.process():
        print(message.body)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():

    print("Connecting")
    connection = await aio_pika.connect_robust(
       host='localhost',
       username='guest',
       password='guest',
       port=5672,
       virtual_host='/',
    )

    queue_name = "test_queue"

    async with connection:
        channel = await connection.channel()

        # Declaring queue
        queue = await channel.declare_queue(
            queue_name, auto_delete=True
        )

        async with queue.iterator() as queue_iter:
            async for message in queue_iter:
                async with message.process():
                    print(message.body)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

If you run this code, and then try stop it by pressing Ctrl+C, first time there will be no effect and second time you press again it will throw an exception. My assumption is in the first attempt it tries to close the connection but cannot.

but instead of using asyncio.run if you run the same code with this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

It will stop the application in your first attempt.
Does anyone have any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: I believe it relates to this: https://github.com/mosquito/aio-pika/issues/379

Comment: And this: https://github.com/mosquito/aio-pika/issues/358